# D3.extent() throws TypeError : Values is not iterable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, react-d3

I have been scratching my head over this for the past three hours, if anyone can help, please do. I am not very adept at D3 in combination with React.

So, basically, I have an anomaly detector algorithm running in the backend Flask App which returns values in form of a dictionary (then converted to json object via json.dumps()) that will, further, be plotted on my React app using D3.

Initially, I thought the problem was with my Database because the app was working perfectly on codesandbox and in all my prior versions.

This is what the console.log(data) looks like :
[image]

I was told that a problem could be with the varying data points for A_Epoch(3) and Time_Epoch(151). Having resolved that didn't help either.

This is what the code looks like:

```
const timeDomain = d3.extent(data, d=>(d.Time_Epoch*1000));
const bytesReadDomain = d3.extent(data, (d) => d.Bytes_Read);
const bytesWriteDomain = d3.extent(data, (d) => d.Bytes_Write);
const bytesSentDomain = d3.extent(data, (d) => d.Bytes_Sent);
const bytesRecvDomain = d3.extent(data, (d) => d.Bytes_Recv);
```

This part is throwing error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`data` is an object, not an array.

`d3.extent` expects an array as the first argument, with the second function in `d3.extent` being an optional key function. That function is executed for every array element. So for example if you have an array of complex objects, with every object having an `id`, you can use the following:

```js
const data = [{
  id: 1,
}, {
  id: 2,
}];

console.log(d3.extent(data, (d) => d.id));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

You actually have an object, where the values are numerical arrays. So instead of

```
const bytesReadDomain = d3.extent(data, (d) => d.Bytes_Read);
```

you should just use

```
const bytesReadDomain = d3.extent(data.Bytes_Read);
```

This is equivalent to `d3.extent([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])`, and doesn't require a key function.

---

For `Time_Epoch`, where you want to multiply all values times 1000, just use [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to apply the same function to all array elements, *before* calling `d3.extent()`:

```
d3.extent(data.Time_Epoch.map((d) => d * 1000);
```